# Left or right action on singular complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading Kirk and Davis's lecture notes and on page 99 they claim that the singular chain complex of the universal cover of a space is a right $\mathbb{Z}\pi$ module.

I believe they use the convention that the composition of functions $f \circ g$ is the function $x \rightarrow f(g(x))$ and similarly composition of loops $\alpha * \beta$ is given by traversing $\beta$ then $\alpha$.

The action makes sense to me: if $\gamma \in \pi_1(X)$ and $\sigma \in C^n(\bar{X})$  take $\sigma$ to $\gamma \circ \sigma$ where we identify $\gamma$ with its deck transformation.

To me it seems like this is a left module since if $\alpha,\beta \in \pi_1(X)$, we have $(\alpha \circ \beta)\sigma=\alpha \circ \beta \circ \sigma=\alpha(\beta \sigma)$.

I have thought about the identification of the fundamental group with the deck transformation group, and I do not think that is the issue.

Comment: Do they not discuss their conventions on pg. 97, just after exercise 73? They take the universal cover to be a *right* $\pi$-space, so $(\sigma\cdot \alpha)(x)=\sigma(x)\cdot \alpha$ is indeed a right action.

Comment: Ah, I just jumped to this chapter after not using the book for a while. Thanks.

Comment: @Tyrone Is it usually thought to be a right action? I am wondering if maybe it uses the opposite convention for the fundamental group, but I don't know if they ever explicitly introduce the fundamental group in this book.

Comment: I think they deal with the fundamental group in chapter 6, at the same time as the higher homotopy groups. It seems like in 6.16.1 they discuss some of their conventions re actions.